# problem when zooming pictures in wxpython

Tags: python, image, wxpython, drawing, zooming

I need to draw over image (to comment over it) in a scrolled panel. I'm having troubles with it since it doesn't behave right when I zoom it in or out. it stops drawing , and then it shows it after a while in a wrong place. right in the upper left corner of the window. and doesn't draw lines correctly .
below is the code for the (`onLeftDown`) function (the button that should draw). the right button event (zoom in). hope it is clear enough.

do you guys have any idea what is going on, and how do I solve it?
thanks in advance

```
def OnLeftButtonEvent(self, event):
    self.curLine = []
    self.x, self.y = event.GetPositionTuple()
    self.CaptureMouse()

def OnMotion(self, event):
    if self.HasCapture() and event.Dragging():
      dc = wx.BufferedDC(None,self.buffer)
      dc.SetUserScale(self.scale,self.scale)
      # to zoom in and out ( increases whenever someone presses the right mouse button
      dc.BeginDrawing()
      dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLUE, 3))
      coords = (self.x, self.y) + event.GetPositionTuple()
      self.curLine.append(coords)
      dc.DrawLine(*coords)
      self.x, self.y = event.GetPositionTuple()
      self.SetXY(event)
      dc.EndDrawing()

def OnRightDown(self,event):
    print self.scale
    self.scale=self.scale*2.0
    self.initDrawing()
    self.maxHeight=self.maxHeight*2
    self.maxWidth=self.maxWidth*2
```

Comment: If the original code you posted is your actual code, one problem you have is an inconsistent use of leading whitespace. In OnRightDown, self.initDrawing() uses a different indent then the previous and next line of code. Perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: no that's not the problem . there is no indentation error but the indentation here on this webpage is missed up . don't know how to fix it in here .

Comment: `self.HasCapture() and event.Dragging():` what does this line supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to scale mouse co-ordinates so that it is in sync with scaling of drawing, so if you are using userScale=2, mouse at x=10 will end up at 20 .
so you need to do this

```
sx, sy = x/cur_scale, y/cur_scale
```

You also need to be do drawing in `EVT_PAINT` event not on onmotion, on motion you just need to refresh window and paint event should take care of what you want to draw.

Comment: btw, you don't need begin/end drawing - they do nothing. (whoops, that should be for Moayyad)

Comment: Actually, the drawing is ok (he's copying the wx demo code) - the EVT_PAINT simply blits the bitmap buffer that is being drawn to in the motion events. This is the code in my drawing program's paint event:

    wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, self.buffer, wx.BUFFER_VIRTUAL_AREA)

Comment: but still .. that does not answer my question , the drawing is fine but not when you use dc.SetUserScale(). did you try it ? or do anyone have another way to zoom image